# I can not add any library refference in my vs2010 which is not compiled in my machine

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I am facing a weird problem with my vs2010. I am having the yellow exclamation sine before my assembly references when I am trying to add an assembly which is not compiled via my machine. When ever i compile the source in my machine and add the reference it works fine .

I dont understand whats happening.

Answer (score 2):

One reason might be the .net version mismatch. The assembly you are trying to add the reference for must be compiled for the same.net version as your project is targeting.

As the default .net version targeted by VS2010 is .net 4.0, some assemblies built for .net 2 or 3.5 would give this problem.
But when compiling on your machine from source you are agin tergeting version 4 and its working fine.

One more possibility is the *Platform Target* option in the Build tab of Project Properties. If the assembly is targeting a specific CPU architecture, your project must target the same too.